# Write user input string to file in C

Tags: c, file-io, io

My program needs to take a user's input and save it to an external file for future reference. Here is the basic outline of the code.

```
void newActivity(FILE *foutput) {
    char name[31];
    char description[141];
    finput = fopen("activities.txt", "a");

    printf("\n What is the name of your activity (up to 30 characters):\n");
    fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);

    printf("\nEnter a brief description (up to 140 characters) of what %s is about:\n",
           fputs(name, stdout));
    fgets(description, sizeof(description), stdin);

    if (finput == NULL) {
        printf("\nCould not open file.");
        exit(1);
    }

    fprintf(foutfile, "%s\n", name);
    fprintf(foutfile, "%s\n", description);

    fclose(foutfile)
}
```

When I run a simple test program that only asks for a name and prints that name, all is good. It looks like this:

```
int main() {
    char name[50];
    fprint("What is your name? ");
    fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
    fputs(name, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Unlike the working test program, my program does not not take any input from the user before moving to the second `printf()` statement. It does read the strings within the `printf` statements, but return a value of `(null)`.

As for writing to the file, the two `fprintf` lines should do it, but I cannot confirm it as the input text has not been properly recorded.

This is a function declared outside of my `main()`. Does that make affect the situation?

Comment: Also, why the function has useless input parameter `finput`?

Comment: You're `printf`ing strings `name` and `description` with the `%d`ecimal format specifier. That makes your program invoke undefined behaviour. It's possible that anything related to `name` and `description` have just been optimised away, or otherwise trashed. Have you tried using a debugger? Edit: As dasblinkenlight points out, that's not your only problem. Please think about what you're writing.

Comment: What is `fprint("What is your name? ")`  - line 3 of `main()`? Where is `newActivity()` being called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
printf("\nEnter a brief description (up to 140 characters) of what %s is about:\n", fputs(name, stdout));
```

`fputs` returns an `int`, while your `printf` wants a string `%s`.

Remove `fputs`, and pass `name` to `printf` instead:

```
printf("\nEnter a brief description (up to 140 characters) of what %s is about:\n", name);
```

Use `%s` when writing out the string to a file:

```
fprintf(foutfile, "%s", name);
fprintf(foutfile, "%s", description);
```

Note that you don't need `\n`, because `fgets` keeps `\n` with the string.

> **From the comments:** My concern is why the program is failing to [read input] for `fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin)`

This commonly happens when your `stdin` has an extra `\n` lingering from a previous operation. For example, if your previous input operation has been reading of an `int` using `scanf`, you would see this effect:

```
scanf("%d", &num);
fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
```

If the user pressed <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the program would set `num` to `5`, but `name` would be set to a string with a single `'\n'`, rather than `'X'`. This is because `scanf` fails to remove `'\n'` produced by <kbd>Enter</kbd> from the buffer, so `scanf` finds it, and thinks that the user just entered an empty string.

Comment: While this is helpful information, it does not address the main issue: The program does not take any input from the user.

Comment: @Naltroc Why, it should! One thing to check is that there's no `\n` in the input buffer prior to calling `newActivity`. This may happen if you call `scanf` with `%d`, `%f`, or other numeric format specifier.

Comment: that does solve the problem regarding returning the proper string. Thank you for that. 
What I am still baffled by is line 7 of the first block of code! It does not take my input. Instead, it prints 9, runs line 10 and takes a longer string, and then returns that string as `"%s", description`, just as it should.
My concern is why the program is failing to do this for `fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin)`.

Comment: @Naltroc Take a look at the edit, this should explain what is going on.